# Identify a SOAP message as request or response

Tags: soap, cxf, interceptor

I have a middleware which can accept the SOAP request and well as can make  SOAP request.

I have written the custom interceptors to  intercept the inbound and outbound request to log them in database.

The issue is that when a SOAP request  is made  the incoming request is intercepted by InBound interceptor and when my module makes the SOAP request it is intercepted by Outbound interceptor which is correct.

But I would like to Identify the incoming SOAP message as weather it is SOAP request or SOAP response so that I can log the SOAP request and Response correctly.

Is there a way to identify the SOAP message as request or response ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use CXF [MessageUtils](http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/message/MessageUtils.html) class to do that. For e.g.:

```
boolean requestor = MessageUtils.isRequestor(message);
boolean outbound = MessageUtils.isOutbound(message);
if (requestor) {
    if (!outbound) {
        //This is your RESPONSE message
    }
} else {
    if (!outbound) {
        //This is your REQUEST message
    }
}
```

Comment: awesome I was looking for this kind of solution but didn't get any so I relied on Http method as mentioned by Moles.

Answer (score 1):

You can always get the headers and look for the TCP header if there is a Request Method of say POST for a SOAP call

Comment: I am not sure but will it be always POST or can it be GET as well

Comment: You seems to be an expert in WS and I am n newbie  to web-services Can  you have a look at **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16526506/catching-the-soap-fault-error-in-custom-interceptor-soap12faultoutinterceptor)** as well

Comment: SOAP is always POST messages, but gets against the WSDL

Comment: So what I did is I am now relying on the request method not null for identifying the SOAP request